# How do I specify some parameter while keeping the parameters before it default in php

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, function-parameter

In functions such as the wordpress function wp_title. I have noticed they can have multiple parameters such as $sep, $display, $seplocation (using wp_title as a example).

I know with Ruby on Rails you can change any parameter such as $seplocation by using `:seplocation => "left"` or `:seplocation => "right"` while still keeping the other parameters as their defualt value. Therefore to bring me to my question: How do you make parameters such as $seplocation a specified parameter while keeping the others their default parameters?

Btw sorry if this is a duplicate, I did search to make sure it was not a duplicate however I am pressed for time and could not search as long as I would like.

Thanks for the help.

P.S. The ruby-on-rails tag was put in because I used ruby on rails as an example for my question.

Comment: Are you talking about function parameters? `wp_title($something, $something_else);` etc...

Comment: yes and i was wondering how to specify later ones ei. $somthing_else while keeping the earlier one the default value ei. $somthing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know WordPress, but to pass arguments to a function and skip some, just pass `null` for the ones to skip:

```
$result = wp_title($sep, null, $seplocation);
```

Comment: Before I mark as accepted does null like saying false or is it like saying inherit the default

Comment: It is not false, it is a null value and if the function has a default it will be used.